# CheckBox disabled in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

i am trying to sending mail in asp.net . when admin send mail to respective email id then admin  check the check boxes and send the email, after this i want to show check box  disabled this is what i want because when admin again login then he will not able to check again in same check boxes because mail already sent  and when new email come then check box must   be enable because admin still not perform any check in new email ...

In my project..when i check in check boxes and click on submit button then email send but when admin again login and then check whether new record comes or not then previous check box always enabled but i want disabled check boxes in previous record because email already send ..

like this

```
emalid 
john_11@gmail.com   (this is new record then  check box enabled)
kety_45@yahoo.com  ( admin already check in this and mail  send then check box must be
 disabled)
```

here is code button code

```
              protected void btnSendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
               string connStr = 
               ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["email"].ConnectionString;
               SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
               string empId = string.Empty;
               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
               try
               {
               mySQLconnection.Open();
               for (int i = 0; i < Repeateremail.Items.Count; i++)
               {
                CheckBox checkboc = 
              ((CheckBox)Repeateremail.Items[i].FindControl("chkSelect"));
                if (checkboc != null)
                {

                    if (checkboc.Checked == true)
                    {
                        string emailId = 
                   ((Label)Repeateremail.Items[i].FindControl("lbl_email")).Text;

                        SendEmailUsingGmail(emailId);
                        dt.Clear();
                        dt.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }


        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            emailsent.Text="Failed";
        }
        finally
        {
            empId = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

this is html

```
                                 <td>
                                   Email
                                </td>


                                <td>
                               Check
                               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll"      
                                   runat="server" 
                               AutoPostBack="true"    
                             OnCheckedChanged="chkSelectAll_CheckedChanged"/>Send   
                                  Mail To All ?

                                </td>
                           </tr>

                          <td>
                                <asp:Label Id="lbl_email" runat="server"
                    Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserEmail")%>'>
                    </asp:Label>

                                </td>
                                 <td>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect"   
                              runat="server"/>
                             </td>
```

Comment: you can put a flag in database for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted isEmailsent like column in your database(the table in which you are storing emails)? (assume initially all are false)
if yes then do something like this...

```
void OnButtonCliked(object sender, eventargs e)
{
   string connStr = 
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["email"].ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
           string empId = string.Empty;
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           try
           {
           mySQLconnection.Open();
           for (int i = 0; i < Repeateremail.Items.Count; i++)
           {
            CheckBox checkboc = 
          ((CheckBox)Repeateremail.Items[i].FindControl("chkSelect"));
            if (checkboc != null)
            {

                if (checkboc.Checked == true)
                {
                    string emailId = 
               ((Label)Repeateremail.Items[i].FindControl("lbl_email")).Text;

                    //you should do something here..like
                    string query = "update loginTable set isEmailSent = 'true' where email = emailID";
                    //execute the query here...

                    SendEmailUsingGmail(emailId);
                    dt.Clear();
                    dt.Dispose();

                  //then use Repeater bind to bind the data...and in repeater bind function you can get the value of checkbox and then set the Repeaeteremail.Items checkboxes to the values updated above
                }
                else if (checkboc.Checked == false )
                {
                     //do samething as above just update the string with isEmailSent = 'false' 
                }
            }
        }    
}
```

Comment: i done in pageload like this ...  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["a"] = em.Depdocuments(Convert.ToString(Session["Login2"]), (Convert.ToString(Session["Login3"])));

                Repeateremail.DataSource = emailll.emailsent(Convert.ToInt32(Session["a"]));

                Repeateremail.DataBind();
            }

            

        }

Comment: why dont you store the such information in database? when you get the login username and password, you can also fetch the checkbox values(as they are important)

Comment: i also store login inforamtion in database

Comment: there is only one checkbx in each row  please see my update question i add html

Comment: updated my answer, just make sure you have set isEmailsent column when you create the Repeater control and set its values acording to the isEmailsent column of db